# NSNumber and float?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, floating-point, nsnumber

I am trying to set an NSNumber as a float value that has been loaded using NSUserDefaults but i'm getting an error. I can't understand why...?

Here's my code:

```
[settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue floatValue] = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"];
```

It works if I use a float on its own (i.e `float myFloat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"]`

, but I want the value available across all view controllers so I have defined it in a model class as an NSNumber.

So, please would anyone be able to advise me on why that statement wont work?

Comment: What is the type `self.sensitivitySettingValue`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

taking settingsData as an object of your datamodel class where sensitivitySettingValue is a variable declared as NSNumber using something as

`[settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue floatValue]`

actually fetches its value rather than setting a float value to it . You can either use the dot notation such as
 `settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"]];`

or something as

```
[settingsData setSensitivitySettingValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"]]];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I got you. Was missing some fundamental understanding there.

Comment: Hey, you mind looking at this question? Think i'm missing something else...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216139/slider-not-behaving-as-i-would-expect

Answer (score 5):

That looks like you're trying to assign a variable to a getter method, judging by your syntax. What does floatValue do? Return a value or assign one?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithFloat:(float)value;
```

method to assign the value. Here is the [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
[settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue setFloatValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"]];
```

Make sure that `settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue` supports `setFloatValue` method.

Comment: If `settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue` returns an `NSNumber`, this will throw an exception because `NSNumber` does not respond to `-setFloatValue:`  Not down voting, because it is not completely clear that the returned object is an NSNumber from the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create NSNumber from float:

```
float myFloat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sensitivityKey"];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat];
// settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue = number; - not sure in type of properties
```

NSUserDefaults also responds to `objectForKey` method, you can save/load NSNumber without casting