# Slider Not Behaving As I Would Expect

Tags: iphone, ios, floating-point, slider, nsnumber

I have a slider that changes a float from 1 to 10 but I want to save this value and use it across all view controllers so I have saved that float as an NSNumber in a model class (settingsData.sensitivitySliderSettingValue).

I am trying to output the updated slider value to the console every time that it is changed however it just gets set to 0 rather than 0 to 10. I don't understand why this is...

Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)sensitivitySliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    [self updateSensitivity];    
}


-(void)updateSensitivity{


    settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sensitivitySlider.value];

    NSLog(@"The Slider Value is: %1.1f", [settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue floatValue]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented your entire code in form of a sample demo and it works as follows

//----------------- .m file

```
#import "SliderDemoViewController.h"
#import "SettingsData.h"

@implementation SliderDemoViewController


-(IBAction)sensitivitySliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    [self updateSensitivity];    
}

-(void)updateSensitivity{

    settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sensitivitySlider.value];
    NSLog(@"The Slider Value is: %1.1f", [settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.value= %f",sensitivitySlider.value);
    NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.minimumValue= %f",sensitivitySlider.minimumValue);
    NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.maximumValue= %f",sensitivitySlider.maximumValue);
}
@end
```

//----------.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SettingsData;
@interface SliderDemoViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet    UISlider*   sensitivitySlider;
    SettingsData* settingsData;
}
-(IBAction)sensitivitySliderValueChanged:(id)sender;
@end
```

Now here **SettingsData** is a datamodel class declared as

//-----------

```
@interface SettingsData : NSObject {
    NSNumber* sensitivitySettingValue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *sensitivitySettingValue;
@end
```

Now the output of updateSensitivity will be something as

```
2011-11-22 09:59:57.259 SliderDemo[691:207] The Slider Value is: 0.0
2011-11-22 09:59:57.260 SliderDemo[691:207] sensitivitySlider.value= 5.581448
2011-11-22 09:59:57.261 SliderDemo[691:207] sensitivitySlider.minimumValue= 1.000000
2011-11-22 09:59:57.261 SliderDemo[691:207] sensitivitySlider.maximumValue= 10.000000
```

If you look at the first line of logs **it will always output 0.00** because we have nowhere allocated settingsData object.

The only point I find **you might be doing something wrong is not creating this object** as

```
if(!settingsData)
{
   settingsData = [[SettingsData alloc]init];
}
```

unless you allocate this object , you will always get 0 as float value while doing an NSLog for the  value for its property sensitivitySettingValue . In case you have allocated this object somewhere make sure you allocate it much before you try to set or retrieve any of its member variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you NSLogged the raw sensitivitySlider.value to make sure the slider itself is setup correctly?

Comment: Next, I would NSLog the numberWithFloat:sensitivitySlider.value result before assigning it to any variable, and if that is also correct, then the problem seems to lie within the settingsData class / sensitivitySettingValue property or variable setup...

Answer (score 0):

make sure the minimumValue and [maximumValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/maximumValue) of the slider are setup correctly

and check you NSLog  **%1.1f** look weird to me. try **%f**

for more troubleshooting please post output of this:

```
NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.value= %f",sensitivitySlider.value)
NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.minimumValue= %f",sensitivitySlider.minimumValue)
NSLog(@"sensitivitySlider.maximumValue= %f",sensitivitySlider.maximumValue)
```